# Doubly linked list with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement doubly linked list in python but am not able to implement deletion properly.

```
def deleteFromBeginning(self):
    if self.listLength()==0:
        print("Can't delete from an empty list")
    else:
        self.head = self.head.next

def deleteFromEnd(self):
    if self.listLength() ==0:
        print("Can't delete from an empty list")
    else:

        current=self.head
        while(current.next!=None):
            current.prev = current
            current = current.next

        current.prev.next = None
        current.prev = None

def deleteFromPosition(self,pos):
    if pos> self.listLength() or pos<0:
        ValueError("Enter a valid position")
    elif pos==0:
        deleteFromBeginning()
    elif pos == self.listLength():
        deleteFromEnd()
    else:
        if self.listLength()==0:
            print("Can't delete from an empty list")
        else:
            current=self.head
            count = 1
            while(current.next!=None and count<pos):
                current = current.next
                count = count+1

            current.prev.setNext(current.next)
            current.next.setPrev(current.prev)
            current.setPrev(None)
            current.setNext(None)

def deleteWithData(self,data):
    if self.listLength()==0:
        ValueError("Can't delete from an empty list")
    else:
        current = self.head
        while current.next!=None:
            if current.data == data:
                current.prev.next = current.next
                current.next.prev = current.prev
                return
            else:
                current = current.next
        print("The value provided is not present")
```

The deletion from beginning and end works fine but deletion with position and data are not giving the desired results.
[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code merely defines several functions; it doesn't run anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One slight refactoring I would do is move your

```
if self.listLength()==0:
            print("Can't delete from an empty list")
```

check to the very top, and not inside the else. This should be one of the very first checks you make.

Other than that, what you can try is keep a track of the previous node:

```
while(current.next!=None and count<pos):
                temp = current
                current = current.next
                count = count+1

        temp.setNext(current.next)
        current.next.setPrev(temp)
```

This should remove the node in the x position, by relinking the previous node to the next node.

Haven't tested it, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hello!
I had tried this method and it works but I was trying to avoid the use of another temporary variable. If anyway we need to use 2 variables to store previous and current position, then what is the advantage of doubly linked list over singly linked list?

Comment: A doubly linked list and a singular linked list has nothing to do with how many variables you use. Forcing yourself to use one variable to handle multiple pointers, just for the sake of it, means you are vulnerable to confusion and less readable code. It's up to you.

Comment: The difference between the two linked list is that, a singular linked list doesn't have a previous pointer, whilst a double linked list does. So a doubly linked list allows traversal in both directions, whilst singular is only one way.